# How to make default text entry value in HTML a multi-word Python variable?

Tags: python, html, input

I am trying to set the default value of a text entry box on an HTML page as a multi-word Python variable, `text_real` (see code below). However, the default value is only the first word contained within that variable. What should I do to have the default value be the entire string (all words)?

```
<label>Title:</label>
<input type = "text"
    id = "title"
    maxlength = "50"
    value = {{title_real}}
    name = "title" />
```

By the way, everything else about this code is running fine: I can, for instance, print out the entire `text_real` value as an HTML paragraph. It's just the text entry default that is causing problems.

Comment: Put quotes around the value.

Comment: `value = "{{title_real}}"`